# Proof that $\mathbb{C}$ is a unique algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I need to prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is a unique (up to isomorphism)
algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ **without** using the following
proposition:

> **Prop**. For any collection of $P \subseteq F[x]$ of non-zero polynomials over a field $F$, a splitting field of $P$ over $F$ exists and is unique up to isomorphism of field extensions; that is, if $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are two splitting fields of $P$ over $F$ then there exists a field isomorphism $\phi: G_{1} \to G_{2}$ with the following commutative diagram where $F \to G_{1}$ and $F \to G_{2}$ are the canonical embeddings:
>
> [image]

It is certainly the case that any nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ splits in $\mathbb{C}$, and we know that $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}(i)$, so $\mathbb{C}$ is **algebraically closed** (by a result from my notes, that says that if any one of 5 equivalent assertions occurs, one of which is that if $G$ is an algebraic extension of some field $F$ such that every nonzero polynomial $f \in F[x]$ splits in G, then $G$ is algebraically closed).

Moreover, $\mathbb{C}$ is an **algebraic closure** of $\mathbb{R}$, since it is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every nonzero polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ splits over $\mathbb{C}$.

However, **without being able to use the proposition quoted above, I am at a loss as to how to show that this algebraic closure is unique**. Could somebody please help me with this? Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Suppose $K$ is some other algebraic closure. Then in particular the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ splits in it. This lets you write down a map $\mathbb{C} \to K$; now prove this map is surjective.

Comment: found the (Khaleesi) movie reference, clip about 100 seconds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFPJIbs2q-o

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the map is $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{K}$ where $f(a+bi) = a+bt$. Then, it is obvious that $ker(f) = 0 + 0i = 0$? And to show it is surjective seems like it should be as obvious - i.e., from the way we have defined $f$, it should be obvious that $\forall a+bt \in K$, $\exists a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$. But, since you said prove it is surjective, I assume there is more to it than just that...Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @ALannister: you can't assume that the only elements of $K$ are of the form $a + bt$; this is equivalent to surjectivity, which is what you need to prove to complete the argument.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan fabulous. So now I'm really lost. I have absolutely no idea what the map should be then.

Comment: The map is what you wrote, that part is fine. I assume $t$ denotes a root of $x^2 + 1$.

Comment: @WillJagy: The clip is funny, but I think the context is lost on me. A deleted comment?

Comment: @tomasz others had commented on the character this OP uses as a user name. My first reference to that was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402890/please-help-me-check-my-proof-that-the-transcendental-numbers-are-dense-in-mat#comment4959176_2402890  after which I was told that I had the wrong queen.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you should have posted this as an answer so you could get points!

Comment: @WillJagy: I see. The Lannister queen is the one whose preferred WMD is explosive liquid. ;-) Khaleesi is the one with dragons.